# Marketing Cloud (Exacttarget) SQL Error "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a query that is pulling data from Synch'd Data Extensions into Shared DE's.  It is a UNION ALL query but not sure that's important.  I have narrowed down running vs erroring to the following line

```
c.cap_ineligible_student_group_count__c as [CAP Ineligible Student Group Count],
```

I looked at the field `CAP Ineligible Student Group Count` in the source and it is Decimal (18,0).  I made sure the Shared DE (Target DE) was the same Decimal (18,0) field type.  I'm still getting the following error back from support:

```
"Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."
```

I'm at a loss - anyone have suggestions?  Support continues to tell me 'developer support for custom SQL is available only to customers who have purchased a Premier Success Plan for their Marketing Cloud account'.  I have a feeling there's something buggy going on here.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd cast that column conditionally.  Something like this:

```
case 
  when isnumeric(c.cap_ineligible_student_group_count__c) = 1 then
    cast(c.cap_ineligible_student_group_count__c as decimal(18,0))
  else 0
end as [CAP Ineligible Student Group Count]
```